# Invoke external library variable with own names

Tags: c#

I have following code using MathNet library

```
Vector<double> vec = new DenseVector(new double[] {4, 5, 6});
```

and if I want to get second value I have to invoke `vec` like that

```
double B = vec[1]
```

And I would like to get second value in `vec` like that

```
double B = vec.y
```

So what code should I write to achieve that behavior?

Comment: A `Vector` is not neccesarily a 2D-vector, it can have n dimensions. Would you want to spent n property-names for that? Like `vector.a, vector.b, vector.c, ..., vector.x,, vector.y`,

Comment: to do that you will need to add a property to DenseVector that returns vec[1], however if you dont have always the same amount of elements you cant code it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Vector is not neccesarily a 2D-vector, it can have n dimensions. So imagine you would have created the following 5-dimensional vector:

```
var v = new DenseVector(new[] { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 });
```

How would you name this vectors properties? x, y, z, a, b?

What you want is not possible, because the alphabet is just limited, however the number of dimensions is not.

Comment: Accually I need only vector.x, vector.y, vector.z, vector.w. Because I write 3D application and I care only about four initial values.
So vector[0] corresponds to vector.x, vector[1] -> vector.y, vector[2] -> vector.z, vector[3] -> vector.w, and I don't want to name next values

Comment: @nemo I understand this, but the compiler doesn´t know that. A vector is not just limited to xyz, it could have any arbitrary number of dimensions. It isn´t neccesarily some geometric point, it could even be some form of temperatur and pressure or whatever value you think of.